# Where should I manage these transactions and how?

Tags: android, transactions

I am doing two transactions on a database using a content provider.

#1st is an update on Table A.

#2nd is an insert on Table B (TABLE 'B' HAS A FOREIGN KEY REFERENCE ON TABLE 'A''s PRIMARY KEY)

1. `row = getContentResolver().`**`update`**`(updatedUri, contentValues, selection, selectionArgs);`
2. `Entry_in_Transaaction_Table_Uri = getContentResolver().`**`insert`**`(myTransactionEntry.CONTENT_URI, contentValues_for_transaction_table);`

Here I want the #2nd transaction to be executed only if the #1st transaction has finished properly.
If anything goes wrong in the #1st or #2nd transaction, it should rollback any changes.
My question is where should I manage these transactions and how? I mean in the `Activity` or in the `ContentProvider` class.
I am fairly new to android programming.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it Conten Provider class is the way to go. Activities and Fragments should only be used to display data on the GUI, an own ContentProvider/API Layer should make the database queries and return the result to the activity/fragment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know we should make database queries on contentProvider but I am unable to do it for different kind of transactions i.e one for update and one for insert and also on different tables.

Comment: @Vivekgupta oh, u mean that u are not able to rollback both changes if the first transaction was succesfull and the second one is not?

Comment: exactly & yeah vice-versa too. @Savan Luffy